# How to make a Vertx Reactive RecordParser emit message without length?

Tags: java, rx-java2, vert.x

I have a reactive vertx  TCPserver, that uses a RecordParser to handle messages with a 2 byte length header. The RecordParser does its job in understanding the length part and the message part.

**Problem 1**
The recordparser , interprets the data and sysouts inside the recordparser correctly. But when I add the following line, the sysouts no longer print. Its probably to do with it executing on a different thread? I am not sure.

```java
frameParser.toFlowable()
         .subscribe(onNext -> System.out.println(onNext));
```

**Problem 2**
Once the line in problem 1 is added, the onNext prints all the data its received in chunks. Which I think I understand, that its forwarding data as it receives.
**Output**

> 5bd34970-da5a-44e1-b167-0d32d2e70bb2
>   OnSuccess
>   ?    [its a non-printable byte 4]
>   12
>   34

My end goal here is to only get the message without the length header. Any pointer will be appreciated.

---

**Code**

```java
// data that is sent by client byte[] b = { 0, 4, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34 };

import io.reactivex.Flowable;
import io.reactivex.Single;
import io.vertx.core.net.NetServerOptions;
import io.vertx.reactivex.RxHelper;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.buffer.Buffer;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.net.NetServer;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.net.NetSocket;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.parsetools.RecordParser;

public class TCPRxServer extends AbstractVerticle {

    Single<NetSocket>        observableNetSocket;
    private FrameToken       expectedToken = FrameToken.SIZE;
    RecordParser             parser, frameParser = null;
    static Flowable<Buffer>  y;
    static Single<NetServer> observable;

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        NetServerOptions opt = new NetServerOptions();
        opt.setIdleTimeout(500); // large to assist in debugging for now
        observable = vertx.createNetServer(opt)
                          .connectHandler(socket -> {
                              frameParser = get2byteFrameParser();
//                              frameParser.toFlowable()
//                                         .subscribe(onNext -> System.out.println(onNext));

                              socket.handler(frameParser);

                          })
                          .rxListen(8888);

        observable.subscribe(onSuccess -> System.out.println("OnSuccess"), onError -> onError.printStackTrace());
    }

    protected RecordParser get2byteFrameParser() {
        return RecordParser.newFixed(2, buffer -> {

            switch (expectedToken) {

                case SIZE:

                    byte[] b = buffer.getString(0, 2)
                                     .getBytes();
                    int frameSize = (((b[0]) & 0xFF) << 8) | ((b[1]) & 0xFF);
                    System.out.println("size: " + frameSize);
                    frameParser.fixedSizeMode(frameSize);
                    expectedToken = FrameToken.PAYLOAD;
                    break;

                case PAYLOAD:
                    System.out.println("Payload: |" + buffer + "|");
                    frameParser.fixedSizeMode(2);
                    expectedToken = FrameToken.SIZE;
                vertx.eventBus() // this solves the sending messsge in the non rx api. When I turn the recordparser to a flowable I still cant get the parser logic to parse.
                     .rxSend("MESSAGE", buffer.toString())
                     .subscribe();

                    break;
            }

        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        TCPRxServer server = new TCPRxServer();
        Single<String> deployment = io.vertx.reactivex.core.RxHelper.deployVerticle(Vertx.vertx(), server);

        deployment.subscribe(id -> {
            // Deployed
            System.out.println(id);
            //
        }, err -> {
            // Could not deploy
            err.printStackTrace();
        });

    }

}
```

**p.s.**
I have tailored the LengthPrefixedStream from SO response of [How to use vert.x-rx to create reactive client-server TCP communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534495/how-to-use-vert-x-rx-to-create-reactive-client-server-tcp-communication)
 with no difference in behavior.

```java
    observable = vertx.createNetServer(opt)
                      .connectHandler(socket -> {
                          new LengthPrefixedStream(socket).toFlowable()
                                                          .subscribe(onNext -> System.out.println(onNext));
                      })
                      .rxListen(8888);
```

Comment: I have partially soved the problem where the recordparser simply uses the event bus to pass the message part along (code updated in question). I am still stuck on turning the recordparser to flowable and the parsing does not kick in, it simply emits the data received in chunks.

Comment: Could you pase the code for your FrameToken class ?

Comment: FrameToken is just an enum.


`public enum FrameToken {
    PAYLOAD, SIZE

}`

Answer (score 2):

From the vertx google user group @tsegismont provided the code that works for me.

**LengthPrefixedStream.java**

```
import io.vertx.core.Handler;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.buffer.Buffer;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.parsetools.RecordParser;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.streams.ReadStream;

public class LengthPrefixedStream implements io.vertx.core.streams.ReadStream<Buffer> {
    private final RecordParser recordParser;

    private FrameToken         expectedToken = FrameToken.SIZE;

    public LengthPrefixedStream(ReadStream<Buffer> stream) {
        recordParser = RecordParser.newFixed(2, stream);
    }

    @Override
    public io.vertx.core.streams.ReadStream<Buffer> exceptionHandler(Handler<Throwable> handler) {
        recordParser.exceptionHandler(handler);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public io.vertx.core.streams.ReadStream<Buffer> handler(Handler<Buffer> handler) {

        if (handler == null) {
            recordParser.handler(null);
            return this;
        }
        recordParser.handler(buffer -> {
            switch (expectedToken) {

                case SIZE:

                    byte[] b = buffer.getString(0, 2)
                                     .getBytes();
                    int frameSize = (((b[0]) & 0xFF) << 8) | ((b[1]) & 0xFF);
                    System.out.println("size: " + frameSize);
                    recordParser.fixedSizeMode(frameSize);
                    expectedToken = FrameToken.PAYLOAD;
                    break;

                case PAYLOAD:
                    System.out.println("Payload: |" + buffer + "|");
                    recordParser.fixedSizeMode(2);
                    expectedToken = FrameToken.SIZE;
                    handler.handle(buffer);

                    break;
            }
        });
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public io.vertx.core.streams.ReadStream<Buffer> pause() {
        recordParser.pause();
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public io.vertx.core.streams.ReadStream<Buffer> resume() {
        recordParser.resume();
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public io.vertx.core.streams.ReadStream<Buffer> endHandler(Handler<Void> endHandler) {
        recordParser.endHandler(endHandler);
        return this;
    }
}
```

**TCPRxServer.java**

```
import io.reactivex.Single;
import io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable;
import io.vertx.core.VertxOptions;
import io.vertx.core.net.NetServerOptions;
import io.vertx.reactivex.FlowableHelper;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.RxHelper;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.net.NetServer;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.parsetools.RecordParser;

public class TCPRxServer extends AbstractVerticle {

    RecordParser       frameParser = null;
    private NetServer  server;
    private Disposable disposable;

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {

        NetServerOptions opt = new NetServerOptions();
        opt.setIdleTimeout(500); // large to assist in debugging for now
        server = vertx.createNetServer(opt);// Create a TCP server

        Single<NetServer> rxSingleServer = server.connectHandler(socket -> {
            LengthPrefixedStream frameParser = new LengthPrefixedStream(socket);
            FlowableHelper.toFlowable(frameParser)
                          .subscribe(onNext -> System.out.println(onNext));

        })
                                                 .rxListen(8888, "localhost");
        disposable = rxSingleServer.subscribe(s -> System.out.println("Server is listening"),
                                              onError -> System.out.println(onError));

    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {

        disposable.dispose();
        server.close(completionHandler -> {
            if (completionHandler.succeeded()) {
                System.out.println("TCPRxServer stopped");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(completionHandler.cause());
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        VertxOptions ops = new VertxOptions();

        // We are using clustered as we have verticles in different VMs and we
        // want to make sure when something is placed on the eventbus, a
        // verticle on a different VM receives it.
        ops.setClustered(true);
        Vertx.clusteredVertx(ops, result -> {
            if (result.succeeded()) {

                Single<String> deployment = RxHelper.deployVerticle(result.result(), new TCPRxServer());

                deployment.subscribe(id -> {
                    System.out.println(id);
                    // Deployed
                }, err -> {
                    err.printStackTrace();
                });

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: So what was the change that fix it? the handler.handle(buffer)?

Comment: handler.handle was one of the things that I was missing when I tried it, plus the imports had to be rectified as the Buffer being used was non reactive instead of reactive in the LengthPrefixer class.

Answer (score 1):

I could not run the code you pasted. If your objective to just get the message without length header, how about the following : (I am not using RecordParser)

```
import io.reactivex.Flowable;
import io.reactivex.Single;
import io.vertx.core.net.NetServerOptions;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.buffer.Buffer;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.net.NetClient;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.net.NetServer;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.net.NetSocket;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.parsetools.RecordParser;

public class NewTCPRxServer extends AbstractVerticle {

    Single<NetSocket>        observableNetSocket;
    RecordParser             parser, frameParser = null;
    static Flowable<Buffer>  y;
    static Single<NetServer> observable;

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        NetServerOptions opt = new NetServerOptions();
        opt.setIdleTimeout(500); // large to assist in debugging for now
        observable = vertx.createNetServer(opt)
                          .connectHandler(socket -> {
                    socket.handler(buffer -> onNewframe(buffer));
                          })
                          .rxListen(8888);

        observable.subscribe(onSuccess -> System.out.println("OnSuccess"), onError -> onError.printStackTrace());
    }

    private void onNewframe(Buffer buffer) {
        int size = buffer.getInt(0);
        Buffer content = buffer.getBuffer(4, size + 4);
        vertx.eventBus().rxSend("MESSAGE", content.toString()).subscribe();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NewTCPRxServer server = new NewTCPRxServer();
        Vertx vertxx = Vertx.vertx();
        Single<String> deployment = io.vertx.reactivex.core.RxHelper.deployVerticle(vertxx, server);

        deployment.subscribe(id -> {
            // Deployed
            System.out.println(id);
            //
        }, err -> {
            // Could not deploy
            err.printStackTrace();
        });

        // a test client
        io.vertx.reactivex.core.RxHelper.deployVerticle(vertxx, new TestTCPClient()).subscribe();
    }

    static class TestTCPClient extends AbstractVerticle {

        @Override
        public void start() throws Exception {

            vertx.eventBus().consumer("MESSAGE", message -> {
                Object body = message.body();
                // we receive 'hello world' here means the TCP server processed
                // it successfully!
                System.out.println("[Message] - " + body);
            });

            NetClient netclient = vertx.createNetClient();
            netclient.connect(8888, "localhost", result -> {

                if (result.failed()) {
                    System.err.println("Client unable to connect");
                    return;
                }
                NetSocket socket = result.result();

                // sending "hello world" every second
                vertx.periodicStream(1000).handler(tick -> {
                    String msg = "Hello world";
                    Buffer frame = Buffer.buffer(msg.length() + 4);
                    frame.appendInt(msg.length());
                    frame.appendString(msg);
                    socket.write(frame);
                });

            });
        }

    }

}
```

I created a test client at the end that is deployed on the same vertx instance.

Comment: I had managed to get the message without the length by placing the payload on the eventbus in my implementation. The second part was how to use the reactive implementation of the recordparser to emit the message without the length, thats the one I am stuck on. But thank you for providing a different way to do it, will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I find rather complicated to use the RecordParser.fixedSizeMode() method for aggregating incoming packets to one message.

For anyone looking for a simpler solution, I advise using **RecordParser.newDelimited**.

If you can manipulate the data sent to your TCP receiver, then instead of prefixing the few first byte of your message length to every message sent, you can suffix a unique delimiter to the end of it.

**code sample**: (I'm not using the RxJava syntax)

**sending**:

```
byte[] serialized = SerializationUtils.serialize(o);
senderSocket.write(Buffer.buffer(serialized).appendString(MSG_DELIMITER));
System.out.println("I sent some bytes: " + serialized.length);
```

**reading**:

```
protected static String MSG_DELIMITER = "_I_Am_so0o_UNIQUEQE_";
protected Vertx vertx;
protected final RecordParser parser = RecordParser.newDelimited(MSG_DELIMITER, new Output());

public static main(String[] args) {
    this.vertx = Vertx.vertx();
    this.vertx.deployVerticle(new Receiver());
}

public class Receiver extends AbstractVerticle {
    @Override
    public void start() {

        NetServer receiver = this.vertx.createNetServer();

        receiver.connectHandler(socket ->

                socket.handler(parser::handle));

        receiver.listen(port, host, res -> {
            if (res.succeeded()) {
                System.out.println("Receiver is now listening!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to bind!");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        System.out.println("Receiver stopped");
    }
}

public class Output implements Handler<Buffer> {

    @Override
    public void handle(Buffer event) {
        try {
            E deserialized = (E) SerializationUtils.deserialize(event.getBytes());
            queue.put(deserialized);
            System.out.println("I received some bytes: " + event.length());

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately when you are working with protocols that prepend length no delimiters come into play. Length prefixing is pretty common on message packed as ISO8583 protocols.