# Vert.x Reading from Partial Bytes of TCP

Tags: java, tcp, netty, vert.x

I want to create a TCP server that accept a certain custom protocol from IoT devices.

In netty, it gives a buffered bytes, and you use read method to get the some (4, 8, 16, n) bytes. Then the operation will return that bytes and moving the buffer index.

If the current buffered byte length is less than requested, then it will wait for the next stream, append it, and the operation begin again.

In asyncio(python) the read(n) have similar functionality.

In vert.x is there a similar method to read buffered bytes like that?? I know that you get Buffer object. But the buffer index will not automatically move it seems? And does it wait for the next bytes??

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [record parser](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_record_parser):

> The record parser allows you to easily parse protocols which are
>   delimited by a sequence of bytes, or fixed size records.

To create a record parser for fixed-size records:

```
RecordParser.newFixed(4, h -> {
  System.out.println(h.toString());
});
```

Record parsers can also be create to consume a `ReadStream`, like a TCP connection input.

Comment: I've found your old answer from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48293954/how-to-make-a-vertx-reactive-recordparser-emit-message-without-length/4843981. But, my message body itself consist of multiple lengthprefixed message. So, how to improved the stream class from that answer to accept these kind of message format??